# lesscss how to escape parentheses

Tags: css, web, less, lessc

I have the following pure CSS rule:

```
#cboxOverlay{
  background:url(images/overlay.png) repeat 0 0; 
  opacity: 0.9; 
  filter: alpha(opacity = 90);
}
```

When I compile it with less (`lessc`) It confuses the `alpha(opacity = 90)` to be a Less function.
How do I escape `alpha(opacity = 90)` to be treated as simple CSS?

Comment: Not sure, but try `filter: ~'alpha(opacity = 90)';`

Comment: @AlonEitan put as answer - it works - tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to [escape](http://lesscss.org/#escaping) strings, you need to wrap it like this `~'<string>'`, it will make the compiler to output the string as-is.

Change:

```
filter: alpha(opacity = 90);
```

To:

```
filter: ~'alpha(opacity = 90)';
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
#cboxOverlay{
  background:url(images/overlay.png) repeat 0 0; 
  opacity: 0.9; 
  filter: ~"alpha(opacity = 90)";
}
```

See also: http://lesscss.org/#escaping